# Accumulator's map method in Play Java?

Tags: java, playframework

In [the official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaBodyParsers) in Play Java, I saw this code.

```
public Accumulator<ByteString, F.Either<Result, User>> apply(RequestHeader request) {
Accumulator<ByteString, F.Either<Result, JsonNode>> jsonAccumulator = jsonParser.apply(request);
return jsonAccumulator.map(resultOrJson -> {
   if (resultOrJson.left.isPresent()) {
       return F.Either.Left(resultOrJson.left.get());
   } else {
       JsonNode json = resultOrJson.right.get();
       try {
           User user = play.libs.Json.fromJson(json, User.class);
           return F.Either.Right(user);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           return F.Either.Left(Results.badRequest(
               "Unable to read User from json: " + e.getMessage()));
       }
   }
}, executor);
```

}

And I don't understand what are `map` and `resultOrJson`?

What should I interpret this although the instance `Accumulator<ByteString, F.Either<Result, JsonNode>>` should not have such a method. In addition, the `resultOrJson` suddenly appears, which makes me puzzled.
Could anyone explain this code?

Answer (score 0):

The Accumulator class has a map() function comparable to Java 8's Stream#map:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.9/api/java/play/libs/streams/Accumulator.html#map-java.util.function.Function-java.util.concurrent.Executor-

In the current context the *resultOrJson* variable represents an `F.Either` object and it is part of a lambda function. If you're unfamiliar with lambdas I recommend you read up on that:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

The functionality is similar to a map() applied to a stream of Map entries. What it does is it basically iterates through each ByteString in the accumulator and *maps* the JsonNode object (if present) in the `F.Either` value to a User value and stores it in a new map.